# Replacements for Intel WiFi Link 5100

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter, minipci

The wireless adapter in my laptop, the Intel WiFi Link 5100, has been really flaky lately.  I've had this laptop for about 8-10 months with no issues.  But over the last week or so, getting it to connect for longer than 10 minutes without spending a half hour to repair the connection has become impossible.

I've searched around for solutions and there seems to be lots of individuals that have had problems with this adapter; with no solution provided (at least none that worked).  So, I'm looking to flat out replace it.

Any suggestions on reliable replacements would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** The Intel WiFi Link 5100 is a WiFi Mini-PCI card.